# WPF/ XAML /C# Datagrid: how to truncate double to certain number of decimal places?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, truncate

My DataGrid receives double variables, I want to truncate them to two or three decimal places.
My xaml code:

```
        <DataGrid Name="McDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  Margin="0, 200, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanUserAddRows="False" />
```

All of my C# code that touches the datagrid:

```
        McDataGrid.DataContext = fillingDataGridUsingDataTable(string input).DefaultView;
        McDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

fillingDataGridUsingDataTable(input) is a function that returns a DataTable with headers in string and values in double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ToString` together with the format specifier [`F`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f) with a precision specifier ([Standard format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#standard-format-specifiers)). The `DataGrid` will convert the double value to a `string` anyway, so `ToString` will do it. Use the overload that accepts a `IFormatProvider` to make the result use the correct decimal separator for the current system's language.

The following example creates numeric `string` from a `double` value with a precision of 3 decimal places:

```cs
double value = 1.23456;
var numericString = value.ToString("F3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // "1.235"
```

To convert the `double` value use the [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0) helper:

```cs
double value = 1.23456;
double roundValue = Math.Round(value, 3); // 1.235
```